# BitBucket - How to link to line in commit

Tags: bitbucket

This link will display MyFile.java in commit abcde:

https://mybitbucket.com/projects/XXX/repos/yyy/commits/abcde#MyFile.java

How can you amend this link so it links directly to a specific line in the file (from the commit)?